# Unable to successfully write jest test for event listener in my webpack entry point

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs, testcase

I'm struggling to understand why one of my tests in Jest is failing.

the test itself is simply to see if i can get any test working that targets a function exported from my webpack entry point, so I picked the easiest matcher I could find. strangely, the test passes as long as the function i've defined in my webpack entry point (which attaches an event listener to an element passed in as an argument) is not called.

however if the function is called with an element passed into it, the test fails with a reference error. I'm including a link to my repo, all you have to do is is npm install and then npm test to see the tests pass, then go into src/client/index.js and uncomment the last line of code at the bottom that turns on the event listener and you'll get the same error message i'm getting.

[image]

I'm utterly lost. I get the feeling i need to do something more than I have in order to set up the jsdom environment but for the life of me i can't figure out exactly what that is. The project I'm working on that this is for is part of my Udacity course work, so you'd think they would have included some videos on how to set up jest with webpack, but nothing. the student mentors they provide haven't even used jest so they have not been able to help me any more than by pointing me at the docs I was already reading.

EDIT: I have tried manually adding the element to the jsdom as in:

```
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.id = 'results';
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

but i'm still getting the same reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from one of the mentors at Udacity.

I failed to realize that global level code is executed when importing into a file. In addition, I was creating the dom elements I needed to exists for my test in jsDOM correctly but needed to have that code come before requiring the function I wanted to test in my .spec.js file.

Problem solved.